# activate button after clicking share button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

I am trying to create a share button which will activate download button after share button is clicked. But the function I wrote is not reliable its working with whats app but not with any other share button.

```
 div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://youtu.be/1IRh28kJOyA" data-action="activate()" data-layout="button" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fyoutu.be%2F1IRh28kJOyA&amp;src=sdkpreparse" data-action="activate()">Share</a></div>
    <a href="#">
            <g:plus action="share" data-href="https://youtu.be/1IRh28kJOyA" data-onendinteraction=activate()></g:plus>
    </a>
    <a onclick="activate()" href="https://twitter.com/share" data-text="Kaarunyam | Ps Anoke Praveen Kumar | Tamil christian song 2017 [official] " data-url="https://youtu.be/1IRh28kJOyA" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a><script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <a onclick="activate()" href="whatsapp://send?text=https://youtu.be/1IRh28kJOyA"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></a>        
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="download" value="Download">
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    document.getElementById("submit").setAttribute("disabled", "disbled");
    function activate()
    {
        document.getElementById("submit").removeAttribute("disabled")
    }

</script>
```

Comment: thanks do you have a solution to my problem

Comment: This code is not complete, cant see `form` opening tag and `div`s are not complete

Comment: <form method="POST" action="mail.php">
        <p>Name
            <input type="text" name="name" required>
        </p>
        <p>Email
            <input type="email" name="email" required>
        </p>

Comment: this is the code start. i don't think that this will make any difference

Comment: try this :function activate() { document.getElementById("submit").removeAttribute("disabled"); }

Comment: @Abhishek You meant he left a semicolon at the end?

Comment: You have a typo:  .setAttribute("disabled", "disbled"); should be "disabled" not "disbled"

Comment: And he says its working for whats app but not others. I am curious about js script that all `a` tag has for sharing purpose

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i am using graph API for Facebook, simple tweet button, and simple google plus share button.

Comment: i am not getting any error. sharing functions are working fine but along sharing one more functions should be called but it is not being called.

Comment: This will not work. The social media buttons are iframes served up from the source so you will not be able to capture the click with your script. This can be proved by removing class="twitter-share-button" from your twitter button then your script will work but you will not have a twitter iframe,

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
  <div onclick="activate()" class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://youtu.be/1IRh28kJOyA" data-action="activate()" data-layout="button" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fyoutu.be%2F1IRh28kJOyA&amp;src=sdkpreparse" data-action="activate()">Share</a></div>
  <a href="#">
    <g:plus action="share" data-href="https://youtu.be/1IRh28kJOyA" data-onendinteraction=activate()></g:plus>
  </a>
  <a onclick="activate()" href="https://twitter.com/share" data-text="Kaarunyam | Ps Anoke Praveen Kumar | Tamil christian song 2017 [official] " data-url="https://youtu.be/1IRh28kJOyA" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>
  <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script><br/>
  <a onclick="activate()" href="whatsapp://send?text=https://youtu.be/1IRh28kJOyA"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
  <br>
  <input style="margin-top:20px;" type="submit" id="submit" name="download" value="Download">
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
  document.getElementById("submit").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");

  function activate() {
    document.getElementById("submit").removeAttribute("disabled")
  }
</script>
```

working fine for me.

just put onclick to the fb-share-button div.

and in plnkr => http://plnkr.co/edit/RjH5jjQhO5gn6ZhCAC8P?p=preview

Comment: its not working code:http://plnkr.co/edit/uxn1jlHhVFfnaLIX8Urs?p=preview

Comment: doesn't work when you use the real share buttons. ie your tweet button. The real buttons use iframes so it will not work.

Comment: any idea how to do this task.